# C# application on port 5000 not showing json

Tags: c#, apache, asp.net-core, production

I have a C# api that returns JSON with a url /api/values but I'm not seeing how you access that from a server. Localhost works fine for development but I can't get to my end point via a production server. Say it's running on port 5000

```
ip-address-here:5000/api/values
```

I should have my json there but nothing shows. I used publish to compile everything like the [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) suggests but I can't get the "localhost" to be an ip address which might be my biggest issue. Are there flags needed when compiling that MS doesn't share in their article?

```
ip-address-here:/var/www/csapi/publish$ dotnet api.dll 
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /var/www/api/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to deploy a simple web api to apache like this. I would appreciate someone pointing out where I'm being a noob to fix this. 
 Running Ubuntu server 16.04 with .NET CORE 2

from launchSettings.json

```
"api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
```

I tried adding UseUrls()method but it didn't make a difference

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseUrls("http://*:5000;https://*:5000;")
.Build();
```

Also give this a shot, but still on localhost...

```
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            //.UseUrls("http://*:5000;https://*:5000;")
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("testCert.pfx", "testPassword");
                });
            })  
            .Build();
```

Comment: Can we see your routing?

Comment: how does your code (Program and Controller) look like? ASP.NET Core includes its own web server, e.g. Kestrel, which you initialise and configure from the Program.cs directly.

Comment: It's the basic web API template that comes with visual studio. The only thing I really changed was to add a class that generates the JSON.

Comment: How did you deploy to apache?

Comment: @WarrenP I ran the publish command then moved that directory to the server which has all the .dll and dependency files. I'm going to reverse proxy but it won't work right now so that's moot at the moment.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#server-urls It is the basics of ASP.NET Core, where you need to change the URL. When it runs at `http://localhost:5000` of course it won't accept your access from `http://ip address:5000` as the two are completely different.

Comment: @LexLi how do I get that too switch the localhost to ip:5000? I tried .UseUrls("http://*:5000;https://*:5000;") but no luck...

Comment: I think in .net core you might need to set an options.Listen for All addresses not just loopback